# import/package beginner's problems

Tags: java, terminal, package

I hava a HelloDate.java on desktop and Second.java in /home/seba/Desktop/programming_Ubuntu/net/sssw/test

```
import net.sssw.test.*;


public class HelloDate{

public static void main(String args[]) {

    System.out.println("from main!");

    Second ob1 = new Second();

    ob1.f();

}

}
```

Second.java :

```
package net.sssw.test;

public class Second{

public Second(){
    System.out.println("from constructor");
}
public void f(){
    System.out.println("from second!");
}

}
```

How can I compile this program with linux ubuntu 14.04 terminal(what commands must I type in), I have JDK installed already.

Comment: for me this worked in case somebody will need it:
"javac -classpath /home/seba/Desktop/programming_Ubuntu HelloDate.java" after that
"java -classpath /home/seba/Desktop/programming_Ubuntu:/home/seba/Desktop HelloDate"

Answer (score 0):

**To compile the file, open your terminal and type**

`javac filename.java`

**To run the generated class file, use**

`java filename`

**compile with jar file**

`javac -cp /path/to/file.jar filename.java`

**If you have multiple classpaths, and/or in separate locations you can separate them with a colon... such as:**

`javac -cp /path/to/file1.jar:/path/to/file2.jar filename.java`

**Once compiled, you can run the java program while including the classpath:**

`java -cp /path/to/file.jar filename`

Hope this will helpful..

Answer (score 0):

execute the following commands

```
cd <java file folder>
javac *.java
java <name of the main class>
here the main class is HelloDate
java HelloDate
```

Hope it helps

Comment: to compile your class file and exeucte the java file.As you are not importing any class file and both the classes are in same package so no need to set classpath explicitly.

Comment: for me this worked in case somebody will need it:
"javac -classpath /home/seba/Desktop/programming_Ubuntu HelloDate.java" after that
"java -classpath /home/seba/Desktop/programming_Ubuntu:/home/seba/Desktop HelloDate"

Comment: -classpath is a flag to mention the jar files which you have used in your java project.So you can use the flag javac -cp <the library or the java file> mainClass.java